# Rails manually set nested attributes in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I am having difficulty understanding the way to layout the view to have the properties nest properly for a nested form.

My params look like this...

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"retsty/G2I1FyYybXm9kVaZi+aPjQm4jsmLdLW3wxsc=", 
  "receipt"=>{"receipt"=>"", "receipt_date(1i)"=>"2014", "receipt_date(2i)"=>"9", "receipt_date(3i)"=>"19", 
  "po_receipts_attributes"=>[
    {"jobquote_order_id"=>{"3"=>"", "5"=>""}, "qty"=>"30"}, 
    {"qty"=>"11"}
  ]},
  "commit"=>"Receive"}
```

The `po_receipts_attributes` array is not nesting the hash correctly.

Format: `po_receipts_attributes: [{jobquote_order_id: <value>, qty: <value>}, {jobquote_order_id: <value>, qty: <value>}]`

According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html, my params should look like this...

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"retsty/G2I1FyYybXm9kVaZi+aPjQm4jsmLdLW3wxsc=", 
  "receipt"=>{"receipt"=>"", "receipt_date(1i)"=>"2014", "receipt_date(2i)"=>"9", "receipt_date(3i)"=>"19", 
  "po_receipts_attributes"=>[
    {"jobquote_order_id"=>"3", "qty"=>"30"},
    {"jobquote_order_id"=>"5", "qty"=>"11"}
  ]},
  "commit"=>"Receive"}
```

I can't seem to get the way to nest an attributes correctly in the view. I have tried many different syntaxes for this.

In my view I have the following code...

```
= hidden_field "receipt[po_receipts_attributes][][jobquote_order_id]", jq_o.id
= text_field_tag "receipt[po_receipts_attributes][][qty]", ""
```

HTML output...

```
<td>
  <input id="receipt_po_receipts_attributes__jobquote_order_id_3" name="receipt[po_receipts_attributes][][jobquote_order_id][3]" type="hidden" />
  <input id="receipt_po_receipts_attributes__qty" name="receipt[po_receipts_attributes][][qty]" type="text" value="" />
</td>
<td>
  <input id="receipt_po_receipts_attributes__jobquote_order_id_5" name="receipt[po_receipts_attributes][][jobquote_order_id][5]" type="hidden" />
  <input id="receipt_po_receipts_attributes__qty" name="receipt[po_receipts_attributes][][qty]" type="text" value="" />
</td>
```

What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
jobquote_orders.each_with_index do |jq_o, i|
  = hidden_field_tag "recepit[po_receipts_attributes][#{i}][jobquote_order_id]", jq_o.id
  = text_field_tag "receipt[po_receipts_attributes][#{i}][qty]", ""
```

Which should generate params:

```
"po_receipts_attributes" => {
  "0" => {"jobquote_order_id"=>"3", "qty"=>"30"},
  "1" => {"jobquote_order_id"=>"5", "qty"=>"11"}
}
```

Which you can later, save(manually as you specified in your question):

```
params[:receipt][:po_receipts_attributes].values.each do |v|
  pr = PoReceipt.find(v['jobquote_order_id'].to_s)
  pr.update_atributes(v.except('id'))
end
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution. Would you be able to allow the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to handle it automatically with that syntax? I thought about using an index like that, but since it didn't follow the API docs, it seems incorrect. I needed to create the view manually (I think) due to the recordset that was returned, or I would have used `fields_for`.

Comment: Yes, you can I presume. If you are using `accept_nested_attributes` then why are you setting them manually at all?

Comment: "due to the recordset that was returned". I need to test the order to see if it is closed prior to it being included in the form.

Comment: It still isn't formatted correctly. This is what was returned when I added the `index` to the `[]`...
    `"po_receipts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"jobquote_order_id"=>{"3"=>""}, "qty"=>""}, "1"=>{"jobquote_order_id"=>{"5"=>""}, "qty"=>""}}`

Comment: I think you misunderstood something from doc. Actually, it says you can have such a hash(as you mentioned in your expected section) then you can save it if you have `accept_nested_attributes`. But, since views send as parameter which is parsed through `ActionController` your actual params should look like the one I've posted.

Comment: @Beengie see the updated answer. You need to change `hidden_field` to `hiddel_field_tag` and then it'll work. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an integer inside the inner `[]` like:

```
= hidden_field "recepit[po_receipts_attributes][1][jobquote_order_id]", jq_o.id
= text_field_tag "receipt[po_receipts_attributes][1][qty]", ""
```

That integer is what keeps the attributes together when Rails parses the form body into the params hash. Each set of `po_receipt_attributes` will need a distinct ID. If you are generating the fields server side you can use `fields_for` and the IDs will be managed for you automatically.

Comment: [http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) shows the attributes array the way I was targeting. Before I asked the question here I tried putting the `jq_o.id` in the `[]` as you have stated, but I didn't see that following the API docs. I'm confused.

Comment: When I have the `jq_o.id` placed in the `[]`, I get... `"po_receipts_attributes"=>{"3"=>{"jobquote_order_id"=>{"3"=>""}, "qty"=>"30"}, "5"=>{"jobquote_order_id"=>{"5"=>""}, "qty"=>"11"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) as the following:

```
<%= form_for @receipt do |receipt_form| %>
  <%= receipt_form.fields_for :po_receipts do |po_receipts_fields| %>
    <%= po_receipts_fields.hidden_field :jobquote_order_id, jq_o.id %>
    <%= po_receipts_fields.text_field :qty %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. The reason why I went this route is due to the fact that I am pulling data from another table into the mix which I have not listed here. jobquote_orders is a many-to-many table and it is driving the number of potential po_receipts for open orders.